# Populating fields, input types etc using JSON

Tags: xml, json

I have a form that works as follows..

Server request builds XML of the data on server side and sends xml, XSL stylesheet then transforms the XML data into the plain html page distributing the data to the relevant/desired locations of the form on the page. Person can view page and edit the populated form, submit back to DB.

I think JSON is more suitable for this from what I have read. The form itself is split into 3 areas, for me this is 3 maps/associative arrays etc each with a name related to the id of an input element etc.

The problem for me comes with having the JSON sent to the page, what should I do with it next in order to achieve the same result as I currently get with XML and XSL.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't have to be an either/or situation.

You can use your XML data and different XSLT stylesheets to render a number of output formats.  JSON can be added as one of those output formats.

Provide different endpoints that the client can use to request:

1. the transformed HTML
2. the transformed JSON
3. the original XML
4. etc.

Using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP), a callback function can be used to take that JSON data and construct an HTML page that performs the same (or similar) post to submit back to the DB.